# Predicate buildTree whose first argument is a list of nodes and whose second argument is a tree

Tags: prolog

I want define a 2-place predicate buildTree whose first argument is a list of nodes (i.e. [a,b,c]), and whose second argument is the tree **tree(a,tree(b,nil,nil),tree(c,nil,nil))**. This is the predicate "tree":

```
tree(nil). 
tree(tree(_,L,R)):-tree(L),tree(R).
```

and this is the predicate "buildTree":

```
buildTree([],nil).
buildTree([X|[Y|H]],tree(X,L,R)):-
   buildTree([Y|H],L),
   buildTree(H,R).
```

but with the query, i.e. `buildTree([a,b,c],T)`, I haven't complex term `tree(a,tree(b,nil,nil),tree(c,nil,nil))`. Why?

Comment: It's failing because it has to call `buildTree([c],R)`, and you have no rule for a one-element list. Another problem is that you're passing `H` in to both recursive calls, so you'd end up with the same elements in both subtrees. And as it is, your problem is a bit under-defined. @user1304831's solution gives the required output for `[a,b,c]`, but will produce extremely unbalanced trees for longer lists, and I don't think that's what you're after. Could you give an example for, say, `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the buildTree correctly, first, you have not defined it for one input, nor two, so logically, your answer will end up incorrect.

it should be more in the line of this:

```
/* Stopping conditions */
buildTree([X | nil], tree(X, nil, nil)). /* First trivial case */
buildTree([X | [Y | nil]], tree(X, tree(Y, nil, nil), nil)). /* Second case */

/* builds a tree, according to your reasoning */
buildTree([X | [Y | H]], tree(X, L, R)) :- buildTree(Y, L), buildTree(H, R).
```

Of course, this is not a binary search tree (for that, you would have to define some logic like treeInsert).

Comment: Unfortunately, with the query **buildTree([a,b,c],T)** Prolog gives me back "false" but I would like T=tree(a,tree(b,nil,nil),tree(c,nil,nil)).

Comment: You seem to be working the wrong way around this: phrase what you want using predicate logic first. Then write it down in prolog. In your original code, of course it would give you "false". The query "buildtree([C], nil)" is not handled, therefor, of course it will be false. First, define what you really want to do with this, in words; my code creates the tree you wanted, but for large inputs it will be terribly unbalanced and with no sorting logic.